# total number oh "Li" in rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Friends i have a loop in which i am getting all number of brand and then i am getting all number of products through an inner loop.Now my question is that i have many brands and against each brand i have many products.Now i just want to show total number of product in digits with "Ul" of each brand.So that user come to know how many products he have in his each brand without clicking brand tab.Here below is code.

> ```
> <ul>
>           <% if @user.brands.count > 0 %>
>            <% @user.brands.each do |brand| %>
>              <li class="inner-list"> <%= link_to brand.title, brand %>
>               <ul> 
>                 <% if brand.products.count > 0 %>
>                  <% brand.products.each do |product| %>
>                   <li><%= link_to product.title, product %></li>    
>                  <% end %>
>                  <% else %>
>                    <p>No Product</p>
>                  <% end %> 
>                </ul> 
>             </li> 
>          <% end %>
>         </ul>
> ```

Comment: And what's your problem / question?

Comment: want to get count of products.like brand A(4) means brand A have four products.

Comment: Did you write this code yourself?

Comment: Try <%= brand.products.count %> or <%= brand.products.size %>before brand.products loop

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic, as OP did not shown any attempt to solve the problem by him(/her)self even though the solution actually is written in the current code. We won't to do your job for you.

Comment: thanks for reply.Yes i have tried it but it gives me count in li.It gives me total number in li not with brand name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this `brand.products.size`

Comment: thanks it works.But how i can append this count with brand name?

Comment: i didn't understand a question,but for example You have brand 'Nike' nike has a products,its simple relation belong_to->has_many,and you count on your object brand how many products it has

Comment: @user3602222 did you learn any basics about Ruby/Rails? Did you make some effort to solve this problem yourself?